# JQuery - Toggle class using !important property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a framework which renders the following mark up:

```
 <div class="menuButton">
    <button id="menuButton">Menu</button>
 </div>
 <ul class="menuList">
     <li><a href="#" tabindex="1" id="nav_home">
                    Home
         </a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" tabindex="1" id="nav_services">
                    Services
          </a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

It also has the following css which shows the menu button on small devices only:

```
 #menuButton {
     display: none; 
 }  

 @media only screen and (min-width : 769px) {
    .menuList {
       display: block !important;
    }
 }  

 
 @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
     #menuButton {
        display: block;
     }

    .menuList {
       display: none;
     }

  }
```

An the following javascript to toggle the menu

```
  $('#menuButton').click(function() {
    $(".menuList").toggle();
    return false;
  });
```

I want to have the menu button displayed regardless of screen size and toggle the menu list i.e. have a mobile menu regardless of screensize. I can do that by overriding the css as follows but I'm unable to override the menulist because it's using the !important property and the jquery toggle function only adds  'style="display: block;" to the element.

```
  #menuButton {
     display: block; 
 }

 @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
   .menuList {
       display: none !important;
   }
 }
```

How can you get the toggle function to add `style="display: block !important;"` or how else can I achieve  what I'm trying to do which is to have a mobile menu regardless of screen size. Note I can only override the css and add my own javascript but cannot edit the outof the box javascript.

Comment: You could use ```toggleClass()```, and apply ```!important``` with the new class included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `toggleClass` you should be able to easily overwrite the `!important` declaration.

```js
$('#click').on('click', function() {
    $('#block').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
#block{
    display: none!important;
}

#block.open {
    display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click">click</div>
<div id="block">block</div>
```